# Data type float

Tags: c++

While declaring a variable of type float, is it necessary to write f towards the end of the value? For example, float amount = .01 and float amount = 0.01f, here what does the f mean and how does it make any difference?Also, what is the role of #include  library file here.

Comment: You have two very different questions in your question. Please keep it to one question per question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between float and double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/what-is-the-difference-between-float-and-double)

Answer (score 5):

It's not necessary: the compiler will make an appropriate numerical conversion for you.

`0.01f` is a *literal* of `float` type, whereas `0.01` is a `double` type.

Occasionally you need to descriminate explicitly especially when working with templates or overloaded functions:

```
void foo(const float&){
    // Pay me a bonus
}

void foo(const double&){
    // Reformat my disk
}

int main(){
    foo(1.f);
}
```

Finally, if you're leading towards using a `float` over a `double`, then do read through this: [Is using double faster than float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426165/is-using-double-faster-than-float)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define your variable. When specifying the type `float` in the definition, adding a trailing `f` is not necessary:

```
float amount = 0.1; /* This is fine, compiler knows the type of amount. */
```

Adding a superfluous literal here (`float amount = 0.1f;`) might even be considered bad practice, as you repeat the type information, resulting in more edits when the type is changed.

In the context of type deduction though, you have to give the `f` literal:

```
auto amount = 0.1f; /* Without the literal, compiler deduces double. */
```

There are more subtle contexts in which type deduction occurs, e.g.

```
std::vector<float> vecOfFloats;

/* ... */

std::accumulate(vecOfFloats.cbegin(), vecOfFloats.cend(), 0.1f);
```

Here, the third argument is used to deduce the type on which `std::accumulate` operates. If you just call it like `std::accumulate(..., 0.1);`, a double to float conversion takes place for every element in `vecOfFloats`.

Answer (score 0):

`.01` is a `double` literal. There is an implicit conversion to `float` in the initialisation

```
float amount = .01;
```

`.01f` is a `float` literal. There is no conversion in the initialisation

```
float amount = .01f;
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends...
You can do for example:

1)

```
float f = 3.14f;
```

In this case the literal 3.14 is explicitly given as a float... so everything is ok

2)

```
float f = 3.14;
```

In this case 3.14 is actually a double, but the variable f is declared as a float...so when compiling, the number will be casted to a float with the loss precision consequences of that case...

You could since c++11

auto f = 3.14;

Or auto f{3,14};

In both cases the compiler takes exactly the type of the literal...(both are doubles)