# How to force de-normals to zero in OpenCL on mac-min

Tags: opencl

In CL 1.1 specification it is mentioned that compiler option *-cl-denorms-are-zero*  says  denormalized numbers may also be flushed to zero.

I'm using CPU on mac-mini as my OpenCL device.
Is there a way to force FTZ?

Comment: You could try executing the code from this answer somewhere in your program: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8217313/139746