# Numpy performance differences depending on numerical values

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I found a strange performance difference while evaluating an expression in Numpy.

I executed the following code:

```
import numpy as np
myarr = np.random.uniform(-1,1,[1100,1100])
```

and then

```
%timeit np.exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.001)**2 )
>> 184 ms ± 301 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

and

```
%timeit np.exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.1)**2 )
>> 12.3 ms ± 34.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

That's an almost 15x faster computation in the second case! Note that the only difference is the factor being 0.1 or 0.001.

What's the reason for this behaviour? Can I change something to make the first calculation as fast as the second?

Comment: On OSX and NumPy 1.15.3, Python 3.7, I see 11ms vs 13ms.

Comment: In Win7, NumPy 1.15.3, Python 3.6.2, I see 227 vs 22 ms

Comment: @jpp I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.6, Numpy 1.15.4

Comment: OK, on Windows, NumPy 1.14.3, Python 3.6.0, I see 97.7ms vs 47.7ms.

Comment: In my system, `exp` of large (negative) numbers are slower: `exp(-1)` is faster than `exp(-1000)`. So it probably comes down to some slower covergence of the `exp` algorithm with large numbers

Comment: @Brenlla yes, that's because division is faster than multiplication.

Comment: @MattMessersmith I mean literally exp(-1) is faster than exp(-1000), without multiplication / division involved

Comment: @Brenlla exp(-1) *does* division under the hood. It's equivalent to 1/exp(1). Division time depends on the size of the operand as well.

Comment: @MattMessersmith Reasonable explanation, but nope. `exp(1)` is still much faster than `exp(1000)`

Comment: @Brenlla Typo: i mean division *slower* than multiplication. But a caveat is that *both* operations depend somewhat on the magnitude of the result: division much more so

Comment: @Brenlla Also `exp(1)` is about the same as `exp(1000)` on my system

Comment: You'll probably have to find the source code of the C function `exp` in the libc library provided by your platform.

Comment: Note that in the slow case, most of the calculations result in *underflow* and return 0.  On my system, I can see the difference quite clearly by timing `exp(a)` with `a = np.full(10000, fill_value=-708.0)` and then with `a = np.full(10000, fill_value=-709.0)`.

Comment: My first guess (based on the title) was that there are some denormalized numbers involved - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781881/why-denormalized-floats-are-so-much-slower-than-other-floats-from-hardware-arch I didn't verify this in all depth for the specific numpy/python setup, but they can be **awfully** slow...

Comment: I'm not seeing any substantial difference between these on my computer, although the first run of the first option was much slower probably due to caching.

Comment: @Marco13, yes, in fact, `exp(-708)` is a normal float,  and `exp(-709)` is denormal, and that's where I see (on Mac OS X) a big jump in execution time.  Underflow to zero doesn't occur until about `exp(-746)`.

Comment: You could use Numba (including SVML) or for such simple cases preferably Numexpr. Case 1 and Case 2 are equally fast and both are faster than Case 2.

Comment: @max9111 Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I first tried with Numexpr and got the same performance difference. I then checked the behaviour with pure numpy and then posted this question.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in the Numexpr timings, but nevertheless Numba works fine in both cases. This is really a weird behaiviour. Both around 3.6ms per call.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Intel SVML

I have no working `numexpr` with Intel SVML, but `numexpr` with working SVML should perform as good as Numba. The `Numba` Benchmarks show quite the same behaviour without SVML, but perform much better with SVML.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

myarr = np.random.uniform(-1,1,[1100,1100])

@nb.njit(error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def func(arr,div):
  return np.exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / div)**2 )
```

**Timings**

```
#Core i7 4771
#Windows 7 x64
#Anaconda Python 3.5.5
#Numba 0.41 (compilation overhead excluded)
func(myarr,0.1)                      -> 3.6ms
func(myarr,0.001)                    -> 3.8ms

#Numba (set NUMBA_DISABLE_INTEL_SVML=1), parallel=True
func(myarr,0.1)                      -> 5.19ms
func(myarr,0.001)                    -> 12.0ms

#Numba (set NUMBA_DISABLE_INTEL_SVML=1), parallel=False
func(myarr,0.1)                      -> 16.7ms
func(myarr,0.001)                    -> 63.2ms

#Numpy (1.13.3), set OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
np.exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.001)**2 ) -> 70.82ms
np.exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.1)**2 )   -> 12.58ms

#Numpy (1.13.3), set OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
np.exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.001)**2 ) -> 189.4ms
np.exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.1)**2 )   -> 17.4ms

#Numexpr (2.6.8), no SVML, parallel
ne.evaluate("exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.001)**2 )") ->17.2ms
ne.evaluate("exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.1)**2 )")   ->4.38ms

#Numexpr (2.6.8), no SVML, single threaded
ne.evaluate("exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.001)**2 )") ->50.85ms
ne.evaluate("exp( - 0.5 * (myarr / 0.1)**2 )")   ->13.9ms
```

Answer (score 1):

This may produce denormalised numbers which slow down computations.

You may like to disable denormalized numbers using [`daz`](https://github.com/chainer/daz) library:

```
import daz
daz.set_daz()
```

More info: [x87 and SSE Floating Point Assists in IA-32: Flush-To-Zero (FTZ) and Denormals-Are-Zero (DAZ)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/x87-and-sse-floating-point-assists-in-ia-32-flush-to-zero-ftz-and-denormals-are-zero-daz/):

> To avoid serialization and performance issues due to denormals and underflow numbers, use the SSE and SSE2 instructions to set Flush-to-Zero and Denormals-Are-Zero modes within the hardware to enable highest performance for floating-point applications.

Note that in 64-bit mode floating point computations use SSE instructions, not x87.